# HAD/HAVE. Mixed tenses vs tenses in harmony

Tags: tense

It seemed as though you, the king, **have** no regards for the lives of the men who protect you.

It seemed as though you, the king, **had** no regards for the lives of the men who protected you.

Could you break down what both the sentences mean?
And what their differences are?

Comment: I think you mean **regard**, in the singular.

Answer (score 1):

> It **seemed** as though you, the king, **have** no regards for the lives of
>   the men who **protect** you.

Someone says this to the king that it **seemed**(past tense - it no longer seems) to speaker that the king doesn't **have** (present tense - King still doesn't have regards for those lives) any respect for the life of men who **protected**(past tense - may have protected at some point in time) the king.

> It **seemed** as though you, the king, **had** no regards for the lives of the
>   men who **protected** you.

Someone says this to the king that it **seemed**(past tense - it no longer seems) to speaker that the king **had** (past tense - King doesn't used to respect those lives but now he does) no respect for the life of men who **protected**(past tense - may have protected at some point in time) the king.